# Cannot use <textarea> in answer?

Tags: support, bug

For [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492290/66580) I had to change the opening angle bracket to `&lt;`. Is this a bug, or established expectation?

Comment: Inside list, you need 4 more spaces so 8 spaces in each line to format it as code. Fixed it for you, see my edit in "side-by-side markdown".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! Now, is it better to delete this question?

Comment: @Antony, someone (like me), might not know the cause is related to having a list running.

Comment: @Fouladpour That's why the duplicate would help those would encounter the same issue in the future. There is a reason why we keep duplicates around instead of deleting them.